# Is it possible to use PAT with 2 WAN IP?

Tags: nat

I have 2 WAN IP (from 2 ISP) and I want to use them for a server behind the router.
Is this possible with NAT/PAT? When I open a session on one of the one IPs can the server respond normally on the same way back?
Or do you know some other method?

Comment: PAT is really made up. The RFCs use NAPT for what some people call PAT. See _[RFC 2663, IP Network Address Translator (NAT) Terminology and Considerations, Section 4.1.2 Network Address Port Translation (NAPT)](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2663#section-4.1.2)_: "_NAPT extends the notion of translation one step further by also translating transport identifier (e.g., TCP and UDP port numbers, ICMP query identifiers). This allows the transport identifiers of a number of private hosts to be multiplexed into the transport identifiers of a single external address._" There is more in the RFC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a single router with two WAN connections, NAT can work.

The bigger problem is using both WAN connections.  You need to define exactly how you want it to happen.  Do you want a simple load-balancing of traffic streams, or something more complex like traffic to/from particular address(es) travel through a specific WAN port?

Comment: I would like to use load balancing. The ISP is limiting the connection so I want to add another one. 
I was thinking about round robin DNS so users wont notice the change but they will use different routes.

Comment: OK. That was a question for you to ask yourself so that you can properly configure the router to use both interfaces. The answer to your question is the first line in my answer.

Comment: Hehe, I had a long day :D Thanks btw!
http://goo.gl/i7ewa9